# I cannot change my automatic incoming certificate in XCode,the wrong certificate is received

Tags: ios, certificate, code-signing-certificate, apple-developer-account

[image][image]While I was developing my project in Flutter, I purchased the developer account required to go to the market on iOS. I added a wrong certificate while defining it in the certificate section, and a certificate with the wrong id automatically appears in the Apple Development section. Whatever I did, I added ios development from the apple development website, etc. But automatically the one with the wrong key came. I deleted it and it comes again. What should I do? Even though I add the correct certified one from the developer account as Apple Development, it brings up the wrong one. When I try to add it manually, it gives an error.

```
Runner has conflicting provisioning settings.
Runner is automatically signed, but code signing identity Apple Distribution: H.... D.... (GZ....B) has been manually specified. Set the code signing identity value to "Apple Development" in the build settings editor, or switch to manual signing in the Signing & Capabilities editor.
```